# Is this a good way to show that $I$ and $J$ are not independent?

Tags: statistics, independence, conditional-probability

Given $$P(I\mid J)=0.7$$$$P(I^c\mid J^c)=0.3$$
does the following bit of working out show that $I$ and $J$ are not independent events?

$$P(I\mid J)P(J)=P(I \cap J)=0.7P(J)$$

$$P(I^c\mid J^c)P(J^c)=P(I^c \cap J^c)=0.3P(J^c)$$

Since $P(I^c \cap J^c)=1-P(I \cap J)$,

and $P(J^c)=1-P(J)$

$$1-0.7P(J)=0.3(1-P(J))$$

$$1-0.7P(J)=0.3-0.3P(J)$$

$$0.4P(J)=0.7 \rightarrow P(J)=7/4,$$ which is silly.

I feel like there's a better way to show that the two are not independent though...

Comment: I do not think it is true that $P(I^c\cap J^c)=1-P(I\cap J)$.  It is true that $P((I\cap J)^c)=1-P(I\cap J)$

Comment: ...was just writing in line 3 you want $P(I^c \cap J^c)=1-P(I \cup J)$

Comment: @Mehness ahhh....that explains it...

Comment: It is quite wrong to say $P(I^c \cap J^c)=1-P(I \cap J).$ Rather, $P((I\cap J)^c) = 1 - P(I\cap J).$ And recall that $(I\cap J^C) = I^c\cup J^c \ne I^c\cap J^c. \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short solution: Assume $I,J$ independent in the space $\Omega$. Then the two $\sigma$-algebras generated by $I$, which is $\{\emptyset, I, I^c,\Omega\}$, and $J$, which is 
$\{\emptyset, J, J^c,\Omega\}$, are also independent, so
$P(I|J)=P(I)$, and $P(I^c|J^c)=P(I^c)$, but the sum $P(I)+P(I^c)\ne 1$, contradiction.

---

Longer solution that follows the thoughts in the OP.

Let us use variables for $P(I), P(J), P(I\cap J)$ to have a simple road through algebraic manipulations. Let us assume $I,J$ independent, and try to get a contradiction. Notations and given relations, under this assumption:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(I) &=: a\in[0,1]\ ,\\
P(J) &=: b\in[0,1]\ ,\\
P(I\cap J) &=ab=: c\in[0,a\wedge b]\ ,\\
P(I\cup J) &=a+b-c\ ,\\
P(I^c\cap J^c)&=P(\ (I\color{red}{\cup} J)^c\ )\\
&=1-P(I\cup J)
\\
&=1-a-b+c
\\
&=1-a-b+ab
\\
&=(1-a)(1-b)\ ,\\[2mm]
0.7&=P(I|J)=\frac cb=a\ ,\\
0.4&=P(I^c|J^c)=\frac {1-a-b+c}{1-b}=1-a\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
contradiction.

Comment: I actually understood the long solution, while did not know what was going on in the short solution. thnx.

Comment: The shorter solution comes to $P(I^c|J^c)=P(I^c)$ in one step. In words, if $I,J$ are independent, then any two events that can be obtained from $I$, respectively from $J$ by "$\sigma$-algebraic operations" (here e.g. taking the complement) are also independent. So $I.J$ are independent, $I^c, J^2$ too, also $I^c, J$, etc. The longer solution computed explicitly $P(I|J)=a=P(I)$ and $P(I^c|J^c)=1-a=P(I^c)$, this is also easy.

Comment: Am i missing something in the short solution? $P(I\mid J)+P(I^c\mid J^c)=0.7+0.3$. How is that not equal to $1$?

Comment: @Arthur The question was edited, so that i cannot recognize it anymore, there was only a long paragraph without centered formulas, at the beginning it was something like $P(I|J)=0.7$ and $P(I^c|J^c)=0.4$ in the text, at least this is what i have in the memory. Now i also cannot see any contradiction... In the second solution i was writing $0.4=P(I^c|J^c)=\dots$ from the given data, else the solution would be an other one, put in the page in a different way.